# Varying recursive function at given depth

Tags: python, recursion, turtle-graphics, fractals

I have a recursive function drawing a fractal, using the python `turtle` module:

```
def fract(t, order, size):
    if order == 0:
        t.forward(size)

    else:
        for angle in (60, -120, 60, 0):
            fract(t, order - 1, size / 3)
            t.left(angle)
```

I have another function calling the first function and modifying the last angle, so that the fractals build a circle

```
def circle(t, order, size):
    for i in range(order):
        fract(t, 2, size)
        t.right(360 / order)

circle(t, 4, 300)
```

While this works as intended, the real goal is to get the same result in a single recursive function.

Obviously this is not a real programming case, but a task from a python beginner's book, which I'm totally stuck with. I suppose the awkward title of the question reflects my lack of understanding the problem.

Comment: Firstly can you update the question to sort out the indentation. Secondly can you explain what `snowflake(...)` is. It looks like a function call, but there is no definition.

Comment: Upps, thanks, done

Comment: Ok, this is currently not recursive. Did you mean for the `fract()` function to call itself? Its currently calling `koch_loop()` with parameters that look like it could call itself.

Comment: *sigh* ... note to self: don't post questions while not yet fully awake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the sentiments of @quamrana on this matter, but let's solve what could be a difficult problem.  With a bit of trickery.

First, your consolidated function has to take four argument as the `order` argument to `circle()` isn't related to the `order` argument to `fract()`.  We'll rename the first of these to `sides()` as that's what it represents.

Second, your `fract()` function isn't completely *recursive*, it uses *iteration* internally.  I'm going to follow that same pattern in my solution.

Finally, we need a bit of hidden information to work with -- you could use a defaulted fifth argument that changes internally but instead I'm going to play with the type of `sides` to achieve this result:

```
import turtle as t

def fract(t, sides, order, size):

    if order == 0:
        t.forward(size)

    elif sides is not None:
        for _ in range(sides):
            fract(t, None, order, size)
            t.right(360 / sides)
    else:
        for angle in (60, -120, 60, 0):
            fract(t, None, order - 1, size / 3)
            t.left(angle)

t.speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience

fract(t, 4, 2, 300)

t.hideturtle()

t.exitonclick()
```

I believe this achieves your desired result with minimal change to your original code.  In addtion to the `fract(t, 4, 2, 300)` invocation, which produces your original figure, we can also do variations like `fract(t, 3, 3, 300)`:

[image]

The next problem you might want to tackle is how to center these images on the screen so that `fract(t, 5, 1, 300)` doesn't fall off the edge.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your `fract()` function is supposed to call itself, then I have been able to run your code successfully.

What you have done is to define a recursive function `fract()` which is called multiple times by your `circle()` function. This is called composing your functions. This is a good thing.

Each of your functions has closely defined behaviour, that is they are cohesive. This means that other programmers can pick up your functions (especially `fract()`) and reuse them in their own programs.

My opinion is that it is best to have many small cohesive functions (and classes and modules) which can be combined in many more ways than were originally intended.

Comment: Thanks @quamrana! While it's good to hear that my solution seems adequate, I wonder if it's even possible to solve this task in a single recursive function. I tried introducing a depth counter, and changing the last angle dependent on the depth, i. e. when `depth % 2 == 0` change to `t.right(120)`, but to no avail.

Comment: While it **is** possible, you would be embedding parts of your `circle()` function inside the `fract()` function which would turn it into a different function which my theoretical *other* programmer would no longer be able to reuse.